# TcpClient can't connect To TcpListener

Tags: networking, tcpclient, tcplistener, socketexception

i want to use a TcpListener - TcpClient connection inside Network.
It is only working when i start the application both on one device, when i use 2 different devices in Network there is this Error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte 127.0.0.1:1300
bei System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
bei System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
 bei System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEP)`bei System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPAddress address, Int32 port)`
```

I thought this is because of Windows Firewall but even when i deactivate the Firewall, the Problem exists.

Server:

```
 ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[1];
                    server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
                    server.Start();

                    clients = new List<TcpClient>();

                    Console.WriteLine("Starte Server ..." + ipAddress + " : " + port);

                    receiver = new List<TCPReceiveMessages>();
```

How i Accept Client:

```
  clientAccepter = new Thread(this.accpeting);                
              clientAccepter.Start();
```

and the Thread inside:

```
private void accpeting()
    {
        //Client socket erstellen
        socketForClient = server.AcceptSocket();

        while (accept)
        {
            //clients werden hinzugefügt
            clients.Add(server.AcceptTcpClient());
            receiver.Add(new TCPReceiveMessages(this));
       }

        socketForClient.Close();
        model.getController().setLoading(false, " ");
    }
```

And well the Client is Connecting to the correct ipAdress and port.

I hope anyone can help me :)

Edit 1: I changed the Ip Adress to 192.168.1.3, because it is inside network, now the TcpClient says that the Server is not reacting after a time span or the connect had troubles because the connected Host didn't react.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that i used wrong ipAdress:

- changed ip adress to 192.168.1.3
- changed port to 5550
- had Problems: disabled Firewall
  -> it worked
- enabled Firewall
  -> it worked too

:) happing codeing